# Is there any Auto-scroll focus in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, windows-10, scrolling, mouse-scroll, focus

In Windows 10, there is a nice new behavior with the scrolling:
When you start to scroll on a window who aren't focus, window acquire the focus and scroll automatically.
In the previous Window and Ubuntu, you have to click, and then scroll, which is not convenient.

I wonder if there any tips in Ubuntu for such a behavior.

Thanks !

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Because in my experience, 14.04 and above have this already.

Comment: Funny - it existed in Linux DEs much before Win10 decided to copy it.

Answer (score 2):

I use Kubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, and I can scroll a background window *without it coming to the foreground*, using the mouse scroll wheel.  All I do is hover the mouse cursor over a visible portion of the window I want to scroll, and roll the wheel.  This in KDE/Plasma desktop, which is the only Ubuntu I've used, so I don't know if the capability exists in other Ubuntu desktop environments.

Comment: The same functionality is built into the default Unity desktop since at least 14.10 as well.